# jquery form labels? Do they not exist?

Tags: jquery, prepend

I'm creating a dynamic input element and I want to set the label for it... I've tried a number of things...

```
//get the value from the input
var getValue = $('#newField').val(); 

//create new input and set default value
var newField = document.createElement("input");
    newField.setAttribute("type", "text");
    newField.setAttribute("name", "s[x]np");
    newField.setAttribute("id", "sx");
    newField.setAttribute("class", "st form-text");
    newField.setAttribute("value", getValue);

$('#addithere').append(newField);

//I've tried all of the following:
newField.prepend("Label");
...

newField.before("Label");
...

$('#sx').prepend("Label");
...

$('#sx').before("Label");
...

var secondItem = "Section: "+newField;
$('#addithere').append(secondItem);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $('#sx').prepend("Label");

This is not the correct syntax for creating a new label element.  You should be using something like this:

```
$('#sx').prepend($('<label/>'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't try `$(newField).before('<label>Your label</label>');` ?

---

Edit:
Maybe you don't have the `$(document).ready(function(){....});`
I tried your code, without this - it didn't work... But with it, it worked!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var getValue = $('#newField').val();
var newField = document.createElement("input");
newField.setAttribute("type", "text");
newField.setAttribute("name", "s[x]np");
newField.setAttribute("id", "sx");
newField.setAttribute("class", "st form-text");
newField.setAttribute("value", getValue);

$('#addithere').append(newField);
$(newField).before('<label>Label</label>');
var secondItem = "Section: "+newField;
$('#addithere').append(secondItem);
});
```

Comment: That was one of the variations I tried... But, that just gives me: this.parentNode is null